# from inline javascript call .removeClass() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I'm making an inline javascript call. It reaches the script but the call to .removeClass() doesn't work (Coldfusion 9).

```
<cfif isDefined('get_contact.C_ADDRESS_SAME') AND get_contact.C_ADDRESS_SAME EQ 0 >       
    <script language="javascript">
        show_address(0);
    </script>
</cfif>
```

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_address(str)
    {
        //alert(str);
        if (str == 0) {
           //   $("#c_address").addClass("hidden");
           $("#c_address").removeClass("hidden");
        }
        else {
            //$("#c_address").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#c_address").addClass("hidden");
        }
    }
</script>
```

The alert works, but removeClass() does not.  When I call it from an onclick event it works fine. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    show_address(0);
});
```

DOM hierarchy need to be fully constructed.Only after that you can access and modify the DOM elements. The handler passed to [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready.

Comment: Can't do it on load, need to wait for a query result.

Comment: what 'query result' did you mean?

Comment: It's part of large application, the call is made only if certain query results are there...<cfif isDefined('get_contact.C_ADDRESS_SAME') AND get_contact.C_ADDRESS_SAME EQ 0 >

Comment: I can't understand your question's context. You had a problem with `removeClass`.So it should work by the answer, I have provided. I can't help you with `coldfusion`'s related problems, I am not specialist of it.

Comment: Gordo - you CAN do it on load. CFML is executed on the server, BEFORE the resulting html/js is returned to the browser/client. I.e. your cfif statement will ALWAYS be processed on the server before any of rendered html/javascript is processed by the browser. Though technically you do not need to call your function at load/DOM ready - just make sure your call is placed AFTER the id="c_address" element, and your show_address function is declared BEFORE that in your source code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your javascript with

```
$(function(){

});
```

This makes sure the DOM is loaded before you start using jQuery.

Comment: Tried that, didn't help, as a side effect though the onClick event stopped working after the change.  Thanks

Comment: Hey Dotty, no, I didn't include it in the code, here it is:<input type="radio" name="as" id="as" value="1" 
                onclick="show_address(this.value)" <cfif isdefined('get_contact.C_ADDRESS_SAME') 
    AND #get_contact.C_ADDRESS_SAME# eq 1> checked="checked"</cfif>> Yes
                <input type="radio" name="as" id="as" value="0" 
                onclick="show_address(this.value)"<cfif isdefined('get_contact.C_ADDRESS_SAME') 
    AND #get_contact.C_ADDRESS_SAME# eq 0> checked="checked"</cfif>> No  --the point is to display additional info if a certain condition exists,and toggle off